# Why x size and y size must be the same for time series prediction with a CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I have to build a CNN to predict molecule code from a time-series of patients entries. The goal is to watch the evolution of certain quantities over time and predict what molecule to give.

To train the network, I use a CNN with a window of length 3. So the network should predict data by "observing" the evolution of quantities over 3 different visits to the doctor, predict the value of the 4th visit, go to the next 3 visits, etc. To create the training data and labels I use the following method: for each patient, take the entries at indices 0,1,2 and predict the next, then take the entries at index 1,2,3 and predict the next, etc. So if a client has 5 entries, I will have 2 labels for the 5 entries as shown in the following (labels are in orange).

[image]

the CNN will have a window of length 3 and a stride of 1 so with 5 entries it only needs 2 labels.

But when I configured the data that way, I have the following error :

[image]

I followed the tutorial of the TensorFlow website, and for what I understand, they did it that way too : [tensorflow time-series tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#convolution_neural_network)

It doesn't work for me, but I don't understand what I don't understand

- here is a collab with my notebook (the first part is for data analysis, the model starts at section `Prediction`): [google collab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Q72iZOyChIQ-Aim5zPAppq2hNMs5fnG4?usp=sharing)
- here is the zip containing the CSV, you don't need to unzip it, just download it in the collab and it works [patients data](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/918273/PatientsHTA.zip)

[EDIT]

this is my x shape and y shape
[image: x shape and y shape]

it is coherent with what I need: x has 5 entries (with 7 features each) and for 5 entries I can only have 2 y (2 features each, the molecule code of the treatment and the time from the last visit)

Comment: Please print out the .shape of your X and Y vectors. The answer to the error is likely there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer, I have to reshape all the data like that: `reshape(1,oldShape[0],oldShape[1]` where `oldShape` is the shape of the data before the reshape